# Django model inheritance: create sub-instance of existing instance (downcast)?

Tags: python, django, inheritance

I'm trying to integrate a 3rd party Django app that made the unfortunate decision to inherit from `django.contrib.auth.models.User`, which is a big no-no for pluggable apps. Quoting [Malcolm Tredinnick](http://groups.google.com/group/django-users/msg/baa3afd55b14ad68):

> More importantly, though, just as in Python you cannot "downcast" with
>   Django's model inheritance. That is, if you've already created the User
>   instance, you cannot, without poking about under the covers, make that
>   instance correspond to a subclass instance that you haven't created yet.

Well, I'm in the situation where I need to integrate this 3rd party app with my existing user instances. So, if hypothetically I am indeed willing to poke about under the covers, what are my options? I know that this doesn't work:

```
extended_user = ExtendedUser(user_ptr_id=auth_user.pk)
extended_user.save()
```

There's no exception, but it breaks all kinds of stuff, starting with overwriting all the columns from `django.contrib.auth.models.User` with empty strings...

Comment: See https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/7623

Answer (score 76, accepted):

This should work:

```
extended_user = ExtendedUser(user_ptr_id=auth_user.pk)
extended_user.__dict__.update(auth_user.__dict__)
extended_user.save()
```

Here you're basically just copying over the values from the auth_user version into the extended_user one, and re-saving it. Not very elegant, but it works.

Comment: Excellent, thanks, Daniel. Got me out of this jam: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18130124/django-two-different-child-classes-point-to-same-parent-class/18132958#18132958.

Comment: You should exclude the pk from the dict or reset it to None before saving. See also the other answer. Otherwise you're just waiting for an IntegrityError.

Comment: man finally resolved . was stuck for too long on this problem . thanks

Comment: Does anyone know how to do this without re-saving/updating all of the fields?? I have tried to specify select update_fields in the save, but I can't figure out what I would need. I have tried (pk, id, user_ptr_id, and parent) and a bunch of more far fetched ones but none work!

Comment: This is giving me an error "cannot set attribute" when using through admin actions

Answer (score 8):

I found this answer by asking on django-user mailing list:

https://groups.google.com/d/msg/django-users/02t83cuEbeg/JnPkriW-omQJ

This isn't part of the public API but you could rely on how Django loads fixture internally.

```
parent = Restaurant.objects.get(name__iexact="Bob's Place").parent
bar = Bar(parent=parent, happy_hour=True)
bar.save_base(raw=True)
```

Keep in mind that this could break with any new version of Django.

Comment: This answer works for Django-Polymorphic too, with an extra step: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74820106/4391298

Answer (score 6):

If you don't like `__dict__.update` solution you can do this:

```
for field in parent_obj._meta.fields
    setattr(child_obj, field.attname, getattr(parent_obj, field.attname))
```

Answer (score 2):

I am using Django 1.6, and my `ExtendedUser` model is from OSQA (`forum.models.user.User`). For some bizarre reason the above solutions with `dict.__update__` and with `setattr` sometimes fail. This may have to do with some other models that I have, that are putting constrains on the user tables. Here are two more workarounds that you can try:

Workaround #1:

```
extended_user = ExtendedUser(user_ptr_id = user.pk)
extended_user.save() # save first time
extended_user.__dict__.update(user.__dict__)
extended_user.save() # save second time
```

Workaround #2:

```
extended_user = ExtendedUser(user_ptr_id = user.pk)
extended_user.__dict__.update(user.__dict__)
extended_user.id=None
extended_user.save()
```

That is, sometimes saving the new child instance fails if you set both `pk` and `id`, but you can set just `pk`, save it, and then everything seems to work fine.

Answer (score 2):

There is an open bug for this very question:
https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/7623

The proposed patch (https://github.com/django/django/compare/master...ar45:child_object_from_parent_model) is not using `obj.__dict__`
but creates an dictionary with all field values cycling over all fields.
Here a simplified function:

```
def create_child_from_parent_model(child_cls, parent_obj, init_values: dict):
    attrs = {}
    for field in parent_obj._meta._get_fields(reverse=False, include_parents=True):
        if field.attname not in attrs:
            attrs[field.attname] = getattr(parent_obj, field.attname)
    attrs[child_cls._meta.parents[parent_obj.__class__].name] = parent_obj
    attrs.update(init_values)
    print(attrs)
    return child_cls(**attrs)

create_child_from_parent_model(ExtendedUser, auth_user, {})
```

This method has the advantage that methods that are overwritten by the child are not replaced by the original parent methods.
For me using the original answers `obj.__dict__.update()` led to exceptions as I was using the `FieldTracker` from `model_utils` in the parent class.

Comment: This seems to work for all fields except ManyToMany fields, which unfortunately is an issue for me. Any ideas what to do if that is the case?

Comment: It preserves the PK, so should work fine for manytomany, unless you mean that your m2m is pointing at the child model, in which case you'll need to alter it to point at the other model.

Answer (score 0):

What about something like this:

```
from django.forms.models import model_to_dict

auth_user_dict = model_to_dict(auth_user)
extended_user = ExtendedUser.objects.create(user_ptr=auth_user, **auth_user_dict)
```

Answer (score -1):

@guetti's answer worked for me with little update => The key was `parent_ptr`

```
parent_object = parent_model.objects.get(pk=parent_id)  
new_child_object_with_existing_parent = Child(parent_ptr=parent, child_filed1='Nothing')
new_child_object_with_existing_parent.save()
```

I wanted to create entry in my profile model for existing user, my model was like

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User as user_model
class Profile(user_model):
     bio = models.CharField(maxlength=1000)
     another_filed = models.CharField(maxlength=1000, null=True, blank=True)
```

At some place I needed to create profile if not exists for existing user so I did it like following,

**The example that worked for me**

```
from meetings.user import Profile
from django.contrib.auth.models import User as user_model

user_object = user_model.objects.get(pk=3)  
profile_object = Profile(user_ptr=user_object, bio='some')
profile_object.save()
```